# MongoDB schema to handle case insensitivity

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I have the users collection. Since MongoDB is case sensitive, I need to reconsider my schema to that I can handle username in insensitive way like in SQL Server.

MongoDB case sensitivity is the root of the problem!!

```
Schema 1:
_id   LowerCaseUserName  email         pwd
Bob   bob                bob@xy.com    ---    
iSpy  ispy               ispy@abc.com  ---

Notes on schema 1:    
 A) There is only one index on _id field in schema 2  
 B) _id is what user entered during signup & shown in URL and pages  
 C) _id is BsonId and app guarantees uniqueness.
 D) There is an index on LowerCaseUserName field & another on email field

Schema 2:
_id   ActualUserName  email            pwd
bob   Bob                bob@xy.com    ---
ispy  iSpy               ispy@abc.com  ---

Notes on schema 2:    
 A) ActualUserName is what user entered during signup & shown in URL and pages    
 B) _id is lowercase of ActualUserName (BsonId) & app guarantees uniqueness   
 C) _id is BsonId andd guaranteed to be unique
 D) There is an index on email field as well
```

These are the queries to support:

```
I) Find if username and password matches (Login)
   The username entered must be treated as case insensitive
2) Check if a username already taken (during new user signup)
3) Check if a given email is already used
4) Update Account
5) Update password
6) Update email
```

Which schema you think would give me better performance and scale well with large number of users in the collection?

Please let me know your thoughts if you need further clarification.

Thank you

Comment: Now that my head has cleared. Why not just store in lowercase and have you application do the conversion? Surely the passwords are hashed. Mixed case in email is not valid. Would that not be the simple approach? This is pretty common so it doesn't seem like good practice to have mixed case in usernames

Comment: Don't worry abt email and password. Read my question again. I have lowercase in both schema design. It is which one will perform better ad scale better.

Comment: That is actually what I just said. What I am trying to understand is your reasoning. Do you already have mixed case usernames? Could you instead live with getting users to convert them. There is obviously additional work required to have essentially duplicate collections. So just thinking of another way around that.

Comment: Usernames are not mixed. You keep what case user entered and another as lowercase. There is no duplicate collection, just one.

Comment: I think my first comment made the point then. Just convert to lowercase in your application. There should be no need to have both fields. SQL server let you get away with something, but MongoDB is not alone in this.

Comment: If this was that easy I wouldn't have posted this. If you store only lowercase, you are losing information which is very vital.

Comment: Since I can see deleted answers it should be noted that even though an index is selected for case insensitive regex it causes a full index scan. It is not as bad as a full collection scan but is still pretty dire. As for case insensitivity: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90 2.7 is going to be an interesting release hopefully